# How to efficiently get items from a list without using get?

Tags: java

For example my current code which finds all elements in the list with a size of 8:

```
 public static void printFamiliesOfLength(int theSize, 
                                    List<AnagramFamily> theFamilies,
                                                PrintStream theOutput) {
        theOutput.println("Families of length: " + theSize);
        theOutput.println("-----------------");
        for(int i = 0; i < theFamilies.size(); i++) {
            if(theFamilies.get(i).getFamilySize() == theSize) {
                theOutput.print(theFamilies.get(i).getCan() + ": ");
                theOutput.println(theFamilies.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is the same thing, but do it without using .get. Right now my program is taking 10 seconds to execute, I'd like to bring that down to like 1 or 2 seconds. Thinking of using iterator but not sure if that would help since it is sort of iterating through anyways?

Comment: is `getFamilySize` a simply getter? or do you do some other logic there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use Java 8, you can do something like this (example is list with Strings):

```
List<String> filteredNames =theFamilies.stream().filter(x ->
x.length()==theSize).collect(Collectors.toList());

filteredNames.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach` loop:

```
for(AnagramFamily anagramFamily: theFamilies) {
    if(anagramFamily.getFamilySize() == theSize) {
        theOutput.print(anagramFamily.getCan() + ": ");
        theOutput.println(anagramFamily);
    }
}
```

This will not use get, but I don't know if the problem is with `get` method.

For performance issue that can avoid situation when you passed big `LinkedList` and use `get(i)` and each time iterating on whole list.

Comment: Since the input is defined as just the interface `List<AnagramFamily>`, this would at least avoid the performance issues from having a potential `LinkedList` passed here.

Comment: This worked for some reason. Took the time from 11 seconds to 1.2 thank you. Not sure why that works quicker though. Anyone know why?

Comment: There has to be something else going on here. There's no reason why a for each loop would be over 9 times faster than a traditional for loop.

Comment: Please profile just the printFamiliesOfLength method and not the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `AnagramFamilyCollection` class to be used instead of the list where you could save the `familySize` in a Map key.

```
 public class AnagramFamilyCollection {
     private List<AnagramFamily> anagramFamilies;
     private Map<Integer, List<AnagramFamilies>> familiesSizes;

     public void insert(AnagramFamily anagramFamiliy) {
       anagramFamilies.add(anagramFamiliy);
       addToMap(familiesSizes, anagramFamiliy);
     }

     private void addToMap(Map<Integer, List<AnagramFamilies>> map, AnagramFamily anagramFamiliy) {
       List<AnagramFamily> list = 
       familiesSizes.getOrDefault(anagramFamiliy.getFamilySize(), new ArrayList());
       list.add(anagramFamiliy);
       familiesSizes.put(anagramFamiliy.getFamilySize(), list);
     }

     public List<AnagramFamily> getBySize(int size) {
        return familiesSizes.get(size);
     }
}
```

Then, you could use it in your method like this.

```
List<AnagramFamily> theFamilies = anagramFamilyCollection.getBySize(theSize);
for(int i = 0; i < theFamilies.size(); i++) {
      theOutput.print(theFamilies.get(i).getCan() + ": ");
      theOutput.println(theFamilies.get(i));
}
```